# Do-while loop wont exit c++

Tags: c++

I got a little problem with my code.. My do-while loop doesn't exit when i give 0 to symbol? I don´t know why because i'm new with c++.. I think that loop needs to quit when the symbol=0?

```
#include "stdafx.h"  
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
char symbol;
double num1, num2;
do {
    cout << "Give the operator (+,-,*,/,0 = quit) : ";
    cin >> symbol;

    cout << "Number 1 : ";
    cin >> num1;

    cout << "Number 2 : ";
    cin >> num2;

    if (symbol == '+')
        cout << "Addition : " << num1 + num2 << endl;

    else if (symbol == '-')
        cout << "Subtraction : " << num1 - num2 << endl;

    else if (symbol == '*')
        cout << "Multiplication: " << num1 * num2 << endl;

    else if (symbol == '/')
        cout << "Division : " << num1 / num2 << endl;

} while (symbol != 0);

cout << "See you";
system("pause");

return 0;}
```

Comment: You probably want `'0'`, not `0`.

Comment: `symbol` is a *character*. Now how is the digit 0 represented as a `char`?

Comment: Typo.  0 is a number, '0' is a character that you would enter

Comment: As for your probable next question: The newline after you input `num2` will be left in the input buffer, to be read by the next `cin >> symbol`. You need to [ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) everything up to the next newline in your input after the last input in the loop.

Comment: Even after fixing 0 with '0' your loop won't exit unless you input number 1 and number 2. I suggest you rethink your solution and add `break` after you enter symbol like this: `std::cin >> symbol; if (symbol == '0') break;`

Comment: I'd suggest ripping the entire "enter number 1 & 2 + the operations on them" into an entire different function... then you can just not call that function. Plus it's a chance to learn about using functions which should be done sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing to `while (symbol != '0');`

In the original version, the comparison was to the number `0` rather than to the symbol `'0'`. Since your input was of type `char` the condition would never be met.

Comment: You may want to consider explaining _why_. (Even though it may seem obvious)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'm kind of new to this and you are absolutely right that an explanation of why would be a much more useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are inputting a coded character into `symbol`, not an integer. When you `cin` into a char, it will capture a coded character from the user rather than a numerical value ze inputs.

```
cin >> symbol;
```

**What is a coded character?**

According to Wikipedia, "code is a system of rules to convert information—such as a letter, word, sound, image, or gesture—into another form or representation." There are many different ways of representing glyphs used in human language, such as numerals, as numbers inside a computer. These ways are called character sets or encodings. Examples of character sets are SHIFT-JIS, ASCII, Unicode, and EBCDIC. These encodings are able to state that a glyph, say `A`, is equal to the number `65`. It does so with every glyph it supports so that each glyph has a unique number.

**How does this relate to my issue?**

Well... assuming that your environment uses the ASCII character set, and your user inputs a `0`, the number your program is going to receive is **NOT** going to be `0`. Instead, it is going to be `48`. This is an issue because your program is checking for the number `0`. Please note that different environments can have different character encodings with different values for different glyphs. Most character sets (but not all!) tend to agree with ASCII on the basic Latin alphabet and Arabic numerals, however.

```
} while (symbol != 0);
```

**How do I fix this?**

The solution is *very* simple. All you have to do is surround the zero you are checking for with single quotes. This will cause your program to check `symbol` for the coded representation of the zero glyph your user input rather than the numerical value of zero.

```
} while (symbol != '0');
```

**What else do I need to know?**

The `char` data type actually isn't that special. It's a number just like the rest of the data types. It was intended for storing character values, however. Variables of type `char` are one byte wide. If a byte is 8 bits, that means that a `signed char` can store any number from `-128` to `127`. You can treat `char` variables **exactly the same as any other scalar integer type in C++**. So what your `char` is actually holding is just a number. Nothing more, nothing less.

The definition of *code* came from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Code&oldid=823846736.