# what's wrong with my code? ( C++ if else with datastructures )

Tags: c++, data-structures

I was working on data structures with C++. Everything looks OK. This is a simple C++ file read. I think this code's output should be:

```
1
K
3
4
5
```

But I'm seeing:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

How can I take `data[4]` in `if`?

**This is file.txt**

```
A(1#Jordan)
A(2#Kyrie)
A(3#Lebron)
A(4#Harden)
A(5#Doncic)
```

**This is my code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

fstream file;
file.open("file.txt", ios::in);

if(file.is_open()){
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        char data[20];
        file >> data;
        
        if(2 == data[2])
            cout << data[4]<< endl; //**
        else 
            cout << data[2] << endl;
    }
}

file.close();
return 0;                                                                     
}
```

Comment: You read ***characters*** into the array `data`. I don't know any character-encoding where `2 == '2'`.

Comment: Also please read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: To extend on Some programmer dude's comment - there are NO (zero, nix) standardised data sets for which `2 == '2'`.   Even if there was such a character set, all C++ (and C) standards require an implementation to have the characters `'0'` to `'9'` as a contiguous set (i.e. `'1' == '0' + 1`, `'2' == '1' + 1`, etc) AND that `'0'` cannot have a numeric value of zero

Comment: Please review [ask]. Your question title is too vague.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do-while loop wont exit c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645315/do-while-loop-wont-exit-c)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `fstream file; file.open("file.txt", ios::in);` to `fstream file("file.txt", ios::in);`. Also, using `ifstream` instead of `fstream` makes things simpler; `ifstream file("file.txt");` is all you need, since `ifstream` is for input. And, finally, you don't need to call `file.close();`; the destructor will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a small error in how you compare a char to an int; the correct comparison is using '2':

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

fstream file;
file.open("file.txt", ios::in);



if(file.is_open()){
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        char data[20];
        file >> data;
        
        if('2' == data[2])
            cout << data[4]<< endl; //**
        else 
            cout << data[2] << endl;
    }
}

file.close();
return 0;                                                                     
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. I learned new information